# How can I set a table cell's background color to red when none of the radio buttons in it are selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript in general and jQuery in particular and need some help.

I need to write a script to validate that a radio button is selected. If none of the radio buttons are selected I want the table cell they are in to be highlighted in red to alert the user about it.

```
<table>
  <tr><td><input type="radio"/></td><td>value 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio"/></td><td>value 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio"/></td><td>value 3</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit"/>
```

**Edit**

I only want the cells containing the radio buttons to be highlighted

Comment: Dude, you have asked over 100 questions and only accepted answers for 59% of them? That kind of reduces my enthusiasm for trying to answer this question.

Comment: @DOK Annoying isn't it? People just don't bother to check it off. :\

Comment: @DOK I do not understand what you mean. In every case I have received answers, I have accepted the answer. If I do not get a response, even if I try to improve the question, how am I supposed to do? Should I remove the question then? I want to do right, and therefore ask for advice what is expected of me.

Comment: You are right. I thought that the green color indicating that I have accepted the answer, but I misunderstood it. I have gone through the questions and accept what I could. I admit that I sometimes forget to accept good answers. But sometimes, I have not received good response and therefore not accepted. Now I have nevertheless chosen to accept several mediocre responses just to get up the percentage, but it does not feel quite right. And how should I do if I received several good answers and can not choose which one to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve it in this way:

```
var IsValid = $("input[name=foo]:checked").length > 0;
$('input[name=foo]').parent().toggleClass('error', !IsValid);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var checked = false;

$('input:radio').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        checked = true;
    }
});

if(!checked){
    $('table').css('background','red');
}
```

Comment: I only want to set the color to the cells containing the radio buttons. And i cant set the id to the <td> as it is auto generated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type='submit']", function(){
    if($("input[type='radio']:checked").size() === 0){
      $("table").css("background-color", "red");
    }else{
      $("table").css("background-color", "white");  
    }
});​
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pHUpm/3/)**

**EDIT**:

For only table rows with inputs and not the whole table, use the following:

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type='submit']", function(){
    if($("input[type='radio']:checked").size() === 0){
        $("table tr").has("input").css("background-color", "red");
    }else{
        $("table tr").has("input").css("background-color", "white");  
    }
});​
```

**[UPDATED EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pHUpm/4)**

Comment: I don't want to set background color for all <td>, only the <td> that containing the <input type="radio">

Comment: You could change `$("table")` to ` $("table tr").has("input")` in that case. Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/pHUpm/4/. I've also updated the answer above to reflect this change.

Answer (score 1):

1)First check whether any radio button is selected or not.

```
var any_checked = false;

$("input:radio").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == 0) {
        any_checked = true;
    }
});​
```

2) Give some id to table,say `id="mytable"`
now check the value of `any_checked`,if its false then no radio button is selected,so throw an error by making cells red.

```
$('#mytable').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

Comment: I only want to set the color to the cells containing the radio buttons. And i cant set the id to the <td> as it is auto generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use .css() function

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){ // <-- this assuming these aren't inside a form
// if it is then do this inside the submit function
// $('yourform').submit(function(){
    $('td').css('background-color',function(){
        return $('input[type=radio]:checked',this).length === 0 ? 'red' : '';
    });
});
```

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/Hydt7/)***

You can use the [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) or [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) selector to filter out the td's with inputs

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
// or $('td').has(input[type=radio])
    $('td:has(input[type=radio])').css('background-color', function() {
        return $('input[type=radio]:checked', this).length === 0 ? 'red' : '';
    });
});​
```

***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/LHhzL/)***

Comment: I don't want to set background color for all <td>, only the <td> that containing the <input type="radio">

Comment: Thanks so much for your great answer, and for helping me to discover Fiddle